# Convert word2vec model file to text

Tags: python, nlp, gensim, arabic, word-embedding

Want to convert gensim word2vec file to txt file, but I get this error:
**UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x80 in position 0: invalid start byte**

ps: The words is in Arabic language.

The mean goal is to build an embedding matrix, if any other solution is available I will be very gratefull.

````
from gensim.models.keyedvectors import KeyedVectors
model = KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format('SG\w2v_SG_300_3_400_10.model', binary=True)
model.save_word2vec_format('SG\w2v_SG_300_3_400_10.txt', binary=False)




``` unicodeDecodeError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-239-fe28681b0b8d> in <module>
     11 from gensim.models.keyedvectors import KeyedVectors
     12 
---> 13 model = KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format('SG\w2v_SG_300_3_400_10.model', binary=True)
     14 model.save_word2vec_format('SG\w2v_SG_300_3_400_10.txt', binary=False)

D:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\gensim\models\keyedvectors.py in load_word2vec_format(cls, fname, fvocab, binary, encoding, unicode_errors, limit, datatype, no_header)
   1628 
   1629         """
-> 1630         return _load_word2vec_format(
   1631             cls, fname, fvocab=fvocab, binary=binary, encoding=encoding, unicode_errors=unicode_errors,
   1632             limit=limit, datatype=datatype, no_header=no_header,

D:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\gensim\models\keyedvectors.py in _load_word2vec_format(cls, fname, fvocab, binary, encoding, unicode_errors, limit, datatype, no_header, binary_chunk_size)
   1900             fin = utils.open(fname, 'rb')
   1901         else:
-> 1902             header = utils.to_unicode(fin.readline(), encoding=encoding)
   1903             vocab_size, vector_size = [int(x) for x in header.split()]  # throws for invalid file format
   1904         if limit:

D:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\gensim\utils.py in any2unicode(text, encoding, errors)
    363     if isinstance(text, str):
    364         return text
--> 365     return str(text, encoding, errors=errors)
    366 
    367 

UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x80 in position 0: invalid start byte
````

The error message.

Comment: How was the `.model` file encoded? Is the error popping up in one of the mentioned lines? If possible post the error message as well.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure the `'SG\w2v_SG_300_3_400_10.model` was saved using `.save_word2vec_format()`? If not, it can't be loaded using `.load_word2vec_format()`.

If it was instead saved using Gensim's native (pickle-based but not pure ython pickling) `.save()`, it must be loaded with `.load()`. And further, it matters whether it was a saved full `Word2Vec` object, or just its constituent word-vectors.

For example, if the model was originally saved via code like...

```py
original_w2v_model.save('SG\w2v_SG_300_3_400_10.model')
```

...then it should be reloaded as:

```py
reloaded_w2v_model = Word2Vec.load('SG\w2v_SG_300_3_400_10.model')
```

But if you'd saved aside *only* the end-result `KeyedVectors`, like...

```py
original_w2v_model.wv.save('SG\w2v_SG_300_3_400_10.model')
```

Then, you could load just those `KeyedVectors` with...

```py
reloaded_kv_model = KeyedVectors.load('SG\w2v_SG_300_3_400_10.model')
```

After you've successfully loaded either the full model, or the vectors, you could then save just the vectors (either `reloaded_w2v_model.wv` or `reloaded_kv_model`) to a text-based format with `.save_word2vec_format(path, binary=False)`.